# Create a controltemplate on a page other than App.xaml and how to call it from other pages

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, controltemplate

I have to create a template common to all pages, only I would like to avoid creating it in the App.xaml page, but creating it in another page makes me mistake when I call it.
This is how I called the template, the page name is Template.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=netstandard"
         xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:GET_SOUND.ViewModels" x:DataType="viewmodels:AppViewModel"
         x:Class="GET_SOUND.Template">
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="HeaderFooterTemplate">
        ...
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

So is the way I call it

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="GET_SOUND.Views.Dashboard"
         xmlns:renderers="clr-namespace:GET_SOUND.Renderers"
         Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
         ControlTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderFooterTemplate}">
```

When I created the template in App.xaml I called it like this and it worked without problems

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 2):

If what you are looking for is to define your control template in a separate file, than you can do that with a [Stand-alone resource dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries#stand-alone-resource-dictionaries) (follow docs instruction on how to add such file in your VS), which you merge with your App.xaml resources:

**App.xaml:**

```
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="TemplatesResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

**TemplatesResourceDictionary.xaml:**

```
<ResourceDictionary       xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="HeaderFooterTemplate">
        <Grid BackgroundColor="Red"/>
    </ControlTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

#### Note

In this sample, the files `TemplatesResourceDictionary.xaml` and `App.xaml` are supposed to be located on the same folder, if it is not the case with your project structure then you have to modify the `Source` property accordingly.

Comment: Does it answers your question or find it helpful ?

Comment: Thanks, later I try to see if I get the desired effect, I am interested that the template is set in a different one from App.xaml, but always in the same project

Comment: Have you been able to test? Any feedback?